# Sending a Post using HttpClient and the Server is seeing an empty Json file

Tags: c#

I'm sending a serialized Json through an HttpClient in C# but the server is seeing an empty object.

The main body that's doing the majority work looks like this:

```
public void create_user(string Email, string Pass)
    {
        try {
            login_information user = new login_information (){ email = Email, pass = Pass };
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ();
            json_functions.serializer (user, user.GetType (), ref stream);
            HttpContent content = new StreamContent (stream);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync ("user/create", content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            string err = e.ToString ();
        }
    }
```

I'm also using a helper function to serialize a class into a MemoryStream, then using that string to make my HttpContent from the StreamContent class.

Here's the json serializer helper function:

```
static public void serializer (Object o, Type T, ref MemoryStream S)
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer s = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer (T);
        s.WriteObject (S, o);
    }
```

And the class that's being serialized:

```
[DataContract]
public class login_information
{
    [DataMember]
    public string email;
    [DataMember]
    public string pass;
}
```

Here's what the Resting API is expecting:

```
{
email:"email@example.com",
pass:"$ExamPLePasSworD$"
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is the correct way to create a json file and send it to the resting api. Yet, the server is still reading it as empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try it without the async

Comment: He's calling .Result on the async method, it's blocking until it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone comes across this in the future, I recently found a solution that worked for me!

I ended up using the json.net library to help make sure my encoding was correct, which in turn gave me a string instead of a string, But that didn't help, and in the constructor for the StringContent class I noticed that you can specify the type of content, and it defaults to white space. So

```
HttpContent content = new StreamContent (stream);
```

became:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Once I specified that it was a json, the receiving Rest API could read the contents. Thank you everyone for all of the help, and happy coding to everyone else!

Answer (score 23):

Most likely issue cause by the fact that you write to memory stream but never reset [Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - so when you call `new StreamContent (stream);` there is nothing after current position in the stream.

Fix recreate memory stream or reset position:

```
stream.Position = 0;
HttpContent content = new StreamContent (stream);
```

Comment: I reset the stream position, and it still showed up as an empty Json file on the server. That was a great idea though!

Comment: @Xirdie Use Fiddler (or other HTTP debugger of your choice) and watch what you actually sending... debug and make sure memory stream actually contains correct information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to await client.PostAsync.

Ninja edit (sorry about that):

The line would look like :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync ("user/create", content).Result;
```

You also have to change the method signature to :

```
public async Task CreateUser(string Email, string Pass)
```

Then you have to await this method!

Answer (score 0):

`StreamContent` doesn't have the convenient ctor for specifying the Content-Type header as `StringContent` does in the accepted answer. You can still use a stream if need by specifing your content type on a separate line.

Replace this:

```
HttpContent content = new StreamContent (stream);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync ("user/create", content).Result;
```

with this:

```
HttpContent content = new StreamContent (stream);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync ("user/create", content).Result;
```