# send file using HttpClient in PostAsync using function app in req.Form.Files c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, azure-functions, httprequest, httpclient

I have created Function App for uploading multiple files on FTP server. I have received all files using `req.Form.Files`. but When I get the request. I actually found my file from `HttpClient` request in `req.Body`. When I upload file from Postman in Body->FormData it, works fine but now I need to send post request with file by code.

I had tried below code with reference of [Sending a Post using HttpClient and the Server is seeing an empty Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785102/sending-a-post-using-httpclient-and-the-server-is-seeing-an-empty-json-file) this link.

```
HttpContent content = new StreamContent (stream);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync ("url", content).Result;
```

But I want file in `req.Form.Files` . Where user might have uploaded multiple files or one file.

Note :  For now I have a file which is being generated by code. But it should not be saved on local so I'm trying to send stream. in `HttpContent`

Comment: Please prefer `await` over `.Result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps for Post Async using function app

```
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            string Connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            string containerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName");
            var file = req.Form.Files["File"];**
            var filecontent = file.OpenReadStream();
            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(Connection, containerName);
            var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filecontent.ToString());
```

File details while using `req.Form.Files`

[image]

Successfully uploaded a text file to blob storage.

[image]

**Edit**:

Here is the Post request Using HttpClient

```
 var file = @"C:\Users\...\Documents\test.txt";
        await using var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file);
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "file");
        using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
         {
            { new StreamContent(stream),"File", "test.txt" }
         };
        request.Content = content;
        await client.SendAsync(request);
        return new OkObjectResult("File uploaded successfully");
```

Comment: I have already tried sending request from postman and it's working fine. I want to call this function app from my app which is in C#. I'm sending request. But I can that file in req.Body. I tried with HttpRequestMessage. Then I found my file in req.Content. Can you please tell how to send request to this function app using HttpClient.

Comment: After publishing the app to Azure, we can send the request using Postman tool or SoapUI tool with the request URL of the published App.

Comment: Yes, That's what I wanted. Thanks alot.